# Replace items in column based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
Date        Value
19990506    0.6
19990506    0.8
19990607    1.2
20000802    0.4
```

and I also have two lists like this:

```
list1 = ['19990506', '19990607', '20000802']
list2 = ['1999201', '1999232', '2000252']
```

the items in `list1` coincide with the values in the column `Date` and I want to replace them with the items that are in `list2`.  So in `Date` `19990506` is replaced with `1999201` and `19990607` is replaced with `1999232`.  I think I need to zip my lists to do this, but after that I am at a loss on the best way to go about it. I am showing a very simplified dataframe so simply using `.replace` is not efficient for me.  My desired output is this:

```
Date      Value
1999201   0.6
1999201   0.8
1999232   1.2
2000252   0.4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create a dictionary that maps from `list1` to `list2` then you can use `Series.map`:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

list1 = ['19990506', '19990607', '20000802']
list2 = ['1999201', '1999232', '2000252']

# When I read in your data I get ints in the Date column
#   so I need ints in the replacement map, if you have
#   strings then remove the int() conversions
replacement_map = {int(i1): int(i2) for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2)}
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(replacement_map)
df
Out[13]: 
      Date  Value
0  1999201    0.6
1  1999201    0.8
2  1999232    1.2
3  2000252    0.4
```